# IE11 - SecurityError zone.js when running angular TestCafe tests

Tags: angular, windows-10, internet-explorer-11, e2e-testing, testcafe

I'm working on a writing e2e tests to an angular 6 project and using testCafe for the tests. Currently, we have 8 tests, and all of the 8 tests are working fine on several servers (Win7, Internet Explorer 11)

but on other servers - 6 pass and 2 fails without any relation to the content of the test. (windows server 2016, Internet Explorer 11)

> JavaScript error details: SecurityError: No stack trace available

when opening the browser's console, the error is:

> SCRIPT5022: SecurityError
>   (zone.js)

[image: error]

this failure happens even if we add empty tests with no logic, change the order of the tests and etc, so the error is not related to a real problem in the test or in the webapp itself.

I've found that IE11 has a limitation on the number of open websockets and it gives the same error message, according to this GitHub bug report:
[IE11 - SecurityError zone.js (192,25) #1001](https://github.com/angular/zone.js/issues/1001)

But unfortunately, both of the answers there didn't solve my problem,
and plus, even if setting the **FEATURE_WEBSOCKET_MAXCONNECTIONSPERSERVER** parameter would have solved the issue, it's limited to 128, and we expect to have a lot of tests in this project.

I also tried to find a configuration in testCafe that will close the browser after each test, but I couldn't find anything similar to this option in their configuration, and "headless" is not supported in IE.

**my question is:** 
as testCafe supports IE11 according to their documentation, is there any configuration or security updates needed in order to run multiple testCafe tests on IE? is there a difference between OS we need to be aware of?

Comment: Did you added the all the necessary polyfills for IE 11? If not, than please try to uncomment the pollyfills for IE in polyfills.js file.

Comment: I added: import 'core-js/es7/object'; import 'core-js/es7/array'; as recommended in the github post but it didnt help, any other polyfills needed?

Comment: Also try to add polyfills for es6 and uncomment all the polyfills for IE regardless its version and try to run your code to check the result.

Comment: You don't need any configuration or security updates to run multiple TestCafe tests in IE 11. 
And, there is no known difference between Windows 7 and Windows Server 2016 for test running.
The behavior you described may take place even without TestCafe.
Could you please try to reproduce the test actions of failed tests in IE manually and find out if there are the same errors?
If so, you first need to fix them.

Comment: Note that TestCafe has [a flag](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/using-testcafe/command-line-interface.html#-e---skip-js-errors) to ignore JavaScript errors that occur on a testing page.

Comment: @HelenDikareva when I run the same scenarios in the browser I get no errors. and I know its possible to ignore JS errors but I prefer to keep it as it may catch a real issue in the future that we would like to address.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT adding polyfills didn't solve it as well. but setting the registry parameter FEATURE_WEBSOCKET_MAXCONNECTIONSPERSERVER  in both HKLM and HKCU solved it, but this will might limit our tests to only 128 tests, any other solution we can try?

Comment: At present, i did not got any other solution for this issue. If I will some to know about any solution or work around than I will try to provide you. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: It seems that there can be a bug in TestCafe. Could you please create [a new issue on GitHub](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?template=bug-report.md) and specify steps to reproduce including your test and the testing page url?
If you have a private project, we will provide you with another secure way to contact us. In this case, only DevExpress employees would have access to provided information.

Comment: Seems that close the dev tools console make it working x)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. My solution is an afterEach callback that closes the websocket through a ClientScript.

```js
// someFixture.js

import {closeWebSocket} from "./client-interaction.js";

fixture("myFixture")
    .afterEach(closeWebSocket)
    .page("http://localhost/");

/* your tests here... */
```

```js
//client-interaction.js

export const closeWebSocket = ClientFunction(() => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        window.myWebSocket.onclose = function() {
            resolve();
        }
        window.myWebSocket.close();
    });
});
```

Note that this example assumes, that the actual WebSocket object/instance is available at window.myWebSocket.